# Python class definition--import statement

Tags: python

I have defined 2 classes- Person & Manager. The Manager inherits the Person class.
I get a error while trying to import the Person class..

Code is give below.

Person.py

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay=0, job=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age  = age
        self.pay  = pay
        self.job  = job

    def lastname(self):
        return  self.name.split()[-1]

    def giveraise(self,percent):
        #return self.pay *= (1.0 + percent)
        self.pay *= (1.0 + percent)
        return self.pay
```

Manager.py

```
from Basics import Person

class Manager(Person):
    def giveRaise(self, percent, bonus=0.1):
        self.pay *= (1.0 + percent + bonus)        
        return self.pay
```

Error statements:

C:\Python27\Basics>Person.py

C:\Python27\Basics>Manager.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Basics\Manager.py", line 1, in 
    from Basics import Person
ImportError: No module named Basics

Why do I get the No module found error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look up how [import and PYTHONPATH](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath) work. In your case, you can solve that using:

```
from Person import Person
```

I see you're coming from a Java background (where each file must have a class with the same name of the file), but that's not how Python modules work.

In short, when you run a Python script from the command line, as you did, it looks for modules (among other places) in your current dir. When you import a (simple) name like you did, Python will look for:

1. A file named `Basic.py`; or:
2. A folder named Basic with a file named `__init__.py`.

Then it will look for a definition inside that module named `Person`.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's in `Person.py`, not `Basics.py`.

```
from Person import Person
```

Answer (score 3):

You defined the `Person` class in a file named `Person.py`. Therefore, you should import it like this:

```
from Person import Person
```

Note that it's the convention in Python to have lowercase module names. For example, rename `Person.py` to `person.py` and `Manager.py` to `manager.py`. Then you'd import the `Person` class like this:

```
from person import Person
```

If the `person` module is part of a package, you'd probably want to import like this:

```
from .person import Person
```

This will ease the transition to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

`from Basics import Person` should be `from Person import Person`. You don't have a Basics.py module to import from.