# i keep getting this error: what Does it mean? NameError: name 'UniversityPerson' is not defined

Tags: python

```
import sys

class UniversityPerson:


 class Student(UniversityPerson):


    def _init_(self, schedule):
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you define your class `Student` inside `UniversityPerson`? Make them the same level:

```
class UniversityPerson:
    pass

class Student(UniversityPerson):
    def __init__(self, schedule): #use double-underscores instead of single ones
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you have to define it and initialize it before you call it? Maybe this link helps: [Python class definition--import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876117/python-class-definition-import-statement)